# Perl - File Iteration and looking for specific matching data

Tags: regex, perl

I'm looking to iterate a file in Perl and if it finds a specific word then store the other lines following that which matches speific pattern.
The ldap.txt file is pretty large in several Gigs.

### user.txt

```
test1  
game
```

### ldap.txt

```
dn: uid=test1,ou=people,dc=admin,dc=local  
blah  
blah  
maillocaladdress: test1@example.com  
maillocaladdress: test.team@example.com  
maillocaladdress: test11@example.com  
some date  
some more data  
data  
dn: uid=game,ou=people,dc=admin,dc=local   
blah  
blah  
maillocaladdress: game@example.com   
maillocaladdress: game.test@example.com  
maillocaladdress: game-test@example.com  
some date  
some more data  
data
```

and so on..

Open user.txt and iterate through each user and check each line on ldap.txt in dn: line.   If matches, then store the value of all the lines matching maillocaladdress to the varialbe , I assume in hash key/value pari but here the values are more than one.

e.g.

```
test1 matches dn: uid=test1,ou=people,dc=admin,dc=local
```

Store the following values for each user.

```
test1@example.com  
test.team@example.com  
test11@example.com
```

code

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $ldiffile = shift;
my %emails;

open my $US, '<', 'users2.txt'
                  or die "Could not Open the file users2.txt: $!";

open my $FH, '<', $ldiffile
                 or die "Could not Open the file $ldiffile: $!";

chomp(my @users = <$US>);
#print "@users \n";

foreach my $uid (@users) {
print "$uid \n";
#       while ( chomp(my $line = <$FH>) ) {
        while (my $line = <$FH>) {
        chomp ($line);
                if ( $line =~ /dn: uid=$uid,ou=People,dc=admin,dc=local/i ) {
                print "$line \n";
                        if ( $line =~ /mailLocalAddress: ([\w\.\-\_\@]+)/ ) {
                                print "<<<< $line >>>> \n";
                                push ( @{$emails{$uid}}, $1 );
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: How big is your `user.txt` file? - nevermind, I see you have loaded it to memory.

Comment: By the way, what's your actual question? What's not working?

Comment: `Several Gigabytes` probably takes a long time to process line by line.

Comment: Crossposted at [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1079590).

Answer (score 1):

Hash the user list. Then, iterate over the second file. Remember what user you are currently parsing ($user). If you see an email address, store it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %users;
open my $USER, '<', 'user.txt' or die $!;
while (<$USER>) {
    s/\s*$//;               #/ Sample input contains trailing whitespace.
    undef $users{$_};
}

my $user = q();
open my $LDAP, '<', 'ldap.txt' or die $!;
while (<$LDAP>) {
    s/\s*$//;
    $user = $1 if /dn: uid=(.*?),ou=people,dc=admin,dc=local/;
    push @{ $users{$user} }, $1 if exists $users{$user} 
                                and /maillocaladdress: (.*)/;
}

for my $user (keys %users) {
    print "$user\n\t";
    print join "\n\t", @{ $users{$user} };
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: I suspect that this line will be too permissive: `$user = $1 if /dn: uid=(.*?),ou=people,dc=admin,dc=local/;`.  It is possible there are `uid` that come up that don't match the other requirements.  Therefore, this will claim a lot of `maillocaladdress` values that aren't actually associated with the `uid` you're tying it to.

Comment: @Miller: I just used the expression from the question (without `/i`). It could be changed according to the data, e.g. to `dn: uid=(.*?),\S+=`

Answer (score 0):

You have some likely flaws in your program.  You're attempting to iterate over the file for each of the @users, but instead you're just looping through the file for the first user only.

What you should do instead is just loop over the file and pull out userids and match them against your list of accepted users.  The following should do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $US, '<', 'users2.txt';
chomp(my @users = <$US>);
close $US;
my %isuser = map {$_ => 1} @users;

my %emails;

my $userid = '';
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^dn: uid=([^,]*)/) {
        $userid = $1;
        $userid = '' if !/,ou=People,dc=admin,dc=local/;

    } elsif ($isuser{$userid}) {
        if (/mailLocalAddress: ([\w.-_@]+)/i) {
            print "$userid - <<<< $_ >>>> \n";
            push @{$emails{$userid}}, $1;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your regex to test for mailLocalAddress has capital letters where as your example data does not.  Therefore put a `/i` flag on the regex.